# How to pass values in a textbox in different forms? Dynamics AX7/365

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations

I have two forms **FormA** and **FormB**.

From **FormA**, I will click a button to open up **FormB**. 
Then I will click another button in **FormB** which will bring me back to **FormA**.

I have a custom textbox in **FormA**, which I need to pass value to it from **FormB**.

In short:

```
FormB --- pass a value to a textbox in --- > FormA
```

I've found this article and we have a very similar problem: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/214344?pi51736=1#responses

However I couldn't understand anything. I am asking for help to those who can enlighten me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What don't you understand? That link you provided is VERY detailed and pretty clear. I think it would be difficult to provide a better answer.

Comment: I am not sure on how to use the args and where to place them. I don't get how to pass the value to the other form.

Comment: I am only using extensions in AX7.